# User Input causes form to appear

Tags: java, android, forms, input

I want to have EditText object appear when a the User chooses "Combination" on a Spinner, How would I do this?

Here is what I have been trying:

```
     ground = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ground);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> groundAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.ground_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    groundAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ground.setAdapter(groundAdapter);
    ground.setOnItemSelectedListener(new GroundListener());
    if(ground.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Combination"))
    {
        combo.setVisibility(0);
    }
```

the EditText object combo is set in xml file as `android:visibility="gone"`

GroundListener Code is

```
     public class GroundListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
            {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a GroundListener ?

Shouldn't you be using an `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` with its `onItemSelected` method ?

Beside, use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` instead of 0 for readability.

**EDIT:**

I don't understand what you are doing with your code, your GroundListener is not plugged to anything and your test is outside of the listener.

Try :

```
ground.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

           if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Combination"))
            {
              combo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
```

Check if that works and then bring back the code in your GroundListener to see if it works. You might have a problem though with the fact that the GroundListener might not know what is  combo. But you'll work that out.

**Edit:**

Syntax Correction

Comment: 'public class GroundListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                  String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
              }

              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
              {
                  // Do nothing.
              }
          }'  That is what GroundListener is. Sorry should have included that in the question. Will edit now

Comment: I still don't know what to do though

Comment: Works. Thanks. I really appreciate it